# A question regarding generalized cohomology and spectra : proof of $E^{\ast}(S)\otimes\mathbb{R} = H^{\ast}(S;\pi_{\ast}E\otimes \mathbb{R})$

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, spectra

I am reading the [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0211216.pdf) *Quadratic functions in geometry, topology and M theory* by M.J.Hopkins and I.M.Singer, and in section 4.8 they say :

> 'Recall that for any compact $S$, and for any cohomology theory $E$ there is a canonical isomorphism 
>   $E^{\ast}(S)\otimes\mathbb{R} = H^{\ast}(S;\pi_{\ast}E\otimes \mathbb{R})$.When $E$ is $K$-theory, this isomorphism is given by the Chern character.
>   The isomorphism arises from a universal cohomology class $
> i_{E}\in H^{0}(E;\pi_{\ast}E\otimes\mathbb{R}) = \varprojlim
> H^{n}(E_{n};\pi_{\ast+n}E\otimes\mathbb{R})$
>   and associates to a map $f:S\to E_{n}$ representing an element of
>   $E^{n}(S)$ the cohomology class $f^{\ast}i_{n}$, where $i_{n}$
>   is the projection of $i_{E}$ to $H^{n}(E_{n};\pi_{\ast+n}E)$.

I do not understand most of the above paragraph. My specific questions are :

> 1.) Where can I find a proof of the isomorphism mentioned ? I am familiar with the basic definitions of spectra and generalized cohomology but can not quite understand the isomorphism. Is this some kind of Brown representability ?
>
> 2.) I do not understand the system of abelian groups over which the limit is taken.

Of course, it is unreasonable to ask for detailed explanations for my doubts. I would really appreciate some hints, and pointers to good texts where I can find a discussion of the above issues and educate myself. Thanks so much !

Comment: I would check Adams's "Stable Homotopy and Generalised Homology". You might also like to check Rudyak's "On Thom Spectra, Orientability, and Cobordism".